# how to read json data for multiple rows in Jquery + wordpress

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

i'm getting following data from json

Return Data:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "name": "abc",
        "meta_value": "3020"
    }, {
        "name": "xyz",
        "meta_value": "3020"
    }]
}
```

i'm using this to encode data   `echo json_encode(array('items' => $data));`

and following to decode and print data from json but it is giving error of

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    $('#dobsondev-ajax-table').append('<tr><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.meta_value + '</td><td>' + data.name + '</td></tr>');

});
```

Comment: The error you provided doesn't look related to the code you've added.

Comment: if i return single line from database and encode it using json_encode then it is ok and display data correctly, even if i use index like this data[0].name the it shows data if i don't put inside loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can use `item` argument inside the loop in the function or you can also try `data.items[i]`.

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    $('#dobsondev-ajax-table').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.meta_value + '</td><td>' + item.name + '</td></tr>');
    //alert(this.name);
});
```

Comment: @coder I think you need to do little more debugging and find which line the error is coming.

Comment: actually this gives error when i put it in loop otherwise it is ok and shows single row for given index , without loop i tried it like data[index].name then it works ,

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the first item in the array directly with `[0]`. The first thing you have to do is retrieving the *items* from your returned data, like this:

```
var items = data["items"];
```

This will give you the two *item* objects of your returned data. From there you can retrieve the two *item* objects like this:

```
var item = items[0];
```

Or in a loop:

```
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: i use this    data = JSON.parse( data ); and then try                $.each(data.items, function (i, item) { item.name }  );

Comment: That should work. See this link: https://jsbin.com/xaxibidoli/edit?html,js,console,output